# Assigning a Series object to a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to do:

```
def processor(self, col):
    # Some work here
    col.fillna(0, inplace=True)
    return col

def main(df):
    pool = Pool(self.cpu_size)
    for series_obj, data in pool.imap(
            processor, [df[i] for i in df[col_list]]):
        print(bool(series_obj.is_copy))
        print(bool(df.is_copy))
        df[series_obj.name] = series_obj
```

But I get a warning:

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.

How can I do the same operation with DataFrame and Series objects without this warning?

p.s.: May be it's a hint that processed series_obj is a column from the initial df, but print(bool(series_obj.is_copy)) returns False and print(bool(df.is_copy)) returns True.

The issue was in the df argument which was created using chained indexing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the df argument which was created using chained indexing. but the error was appear during execution of the main function.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong with what you are trying to do so long as `series_obj` has a compatible index.

The issue is with how you constructed `df`.  It was created in such a way that it is labeled as a view of another dataframe.  You can verify this by typing `bool(df.is_copy)`.  It should come back `True`

So, make your `df` not a view anymore by:

```
df = df.copy()
```

This will disentangle it from what ever other dataframe it was formed from. Mind you, that if you wanted this entanglement, it will no longer be!

Then you can

```
df[series_obj.name] = series_obj
```

---

Side note:  I can't actually recreate this in 0.20

```
df_source = pd.DataFrame(1, list('abc'), list('xyz'))

df = df_source[['x', 'z']]

series_obj = pd.Series(2, list('abc'))

print(bool(df.is_copy))

df[series_obj.name] = series_obj

print(bool(df.is_copy))

True
False
```

Comment: It's really tricky and I can't replicate the issue with this simple script also. I added more details to my post.